# R Rvest for() and Error server error: (503) Service Unavailable

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, scrape, rvest

I'm  new to webscraping, but I am excited using `rvest` in R. 
I tried to use it to scrape particular data of companies.
I have created a for loop (171 urls), and when I am running it stops on 6th or 7th url with an error

```
Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = encoding) : 
  server error: (503) Service Unavailable
```

When I start my loop from 7th url it goes for two or three more and stops again with the same error.
My loop

```
library(rvest)    
thing<-c("http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LA-VIS-S-C-A",                                                                                  
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ L-ANGOLO-DEL-DOLCE-DI-OBEROSLER-MARCO",                                                         
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ MARCHI-LAURA",                                                                                 
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LAVIS-PIZZA-DI-GASPARETTO-MATTEO",                                                              
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-DELIZIE-MOCHENE-DI-OSLER-NICOLA",                                                            
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-DELIZIE-S-N-C-DI-GAMBONI-PIETRO-E-PISONI-MAURO-C-IN-SIGLA-LE-DELIZIE-S-N-C",                 
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-FONTI-DISTILLATI-DI-COVI-MARCELLO",                                                          
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-MIGOLE-DI-MATTEOTTI-LUCA",                                                                   
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LECHTHALER-DI-TOGN-LUIGI-E-C-S-N-C",                                                            
    "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LETRARI-AZ-AGRICOLA")

    thing<-gsub(" ", "", thing)

    d <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=4)
    colnames(d)<-c("RAGIONE SOCIALE",'ATTIVITA', 'INDIRIZZO', 'CAP')

    for(i in 1:10) {
            a<-thing[i]

            urls<-html(a)

            d[i,2] <- try({ urls %>% html_node(".span") %>% html_text() }, silent=TRUE)
    }
```

May be there is a way to avoid this error, thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated.

UPD
With next code, I am trying to restart the loop of fetching data, from the last successful one with `repeat()`, but it is looping infinitely, hope for some suggestions.

```
    for(i in 1:10) {

  a<-thing[i]

  try({d[i,2]<- try({html(a) }, silent=TRUE)  %>%
         html_node(".span") %>%
         html_text() }, silent=TRUE)

  repeat {try({d[i,2]<- try({html(a) }, silent=TRUE)  %>%
                 html_node(".span") %>%
                 html_text() }, silent=TRUE)}
  if (!is.na(d[i,2])) break
}
```

Or with `while()`

```
for(i in 1:10) {

  a<-thing[i]

while (is.na(d[i,2])) {
  try({d[i,2]<-try({html(a) %>%html_node(".span")},silent=TRUE) %>% html_text() },silent=TRUE)
}
}
```

`While()` works but not so good and too slow ((

Comment: Most likely those web pages are [not available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) - I don't think this has anything to do with `rvest` itself. You could use `try(..., silent=TRUE)` to skip the broken URLs.

Comment: @nrussell , maybe some function type of `if else`,`if` error `else(then)` restart the loop from the last+1 resultative url. But i can't imagine a code of it) Will it be efficient?

Comment: `d[i,2] <- try({
  urls %>% 
    html_node(".span") %>%
    html_text()
  }, silent=TRUE)` would probably work fine.

Comment: @nrussell, thanks but still gives 2 or 3 in average but not more)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what your data looks like so it's impossible to say what's going wrong.

Comment: @nrussell I have updated a code, maybe it will be useful to solve the problem, thanks for your time

Comment: @DimaSukhorukov, the problem is that the error occurs on the `html()` call, which you have placed outside of your `try()` block. Move the `urls<-html(a)` statement inside the `try()` block and it will work.

Comment: @bgoldst thank you, if I understood right, that movement is right? `for(i in 1:10) {
        a<-thing[i]
d[i,2] <- try({ html(a) %>% html_node(".span") %>% html_text() }, silent=TRUE)
}` it doesn't gives an error but fill matrix with (Error in parse.response(r, parser, encoding = e), urls are right.... hmm am i doing smth wrong?

Comment: @DimaSukhorukov, yes, that's correct. Now the issue is that the assignment `d[i,2] <-` is outside the `try()` block. If you move that inside, then the assignment will not take place at all if there's an error.

Comment: @bgoldst and as a results i will get or an error 503 in cell of matrix, or NA value. hope it is not a final solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like if you hit that site too quickly, you get a 503. Add a `Sys.sleep(2)` and all 10 iterations worked for me...

```
library(rvest)    
thing<-c("http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LA-VIS-S-C-A",                                                                                  
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ L-ANGOLO-DEL-DOLCE-DI-OBEROSLER-MARCO",                                                         
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ MARCHI-LAURA",                                                                                 
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LAVIS-PIZZA-DI-GASPARETTO-MATTEO",                                                              
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-DELIZIE-MOCHENE-DI-OSLER-NICOLA",                                                            
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-DELIZIE-S-N-C-DI-GAMBONI-PIETRO-E-PISONI-MAURO-C-IN-SIGLA-LE-DELIZIE-S-N-C",                 
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-FONTI-DISTILLATI-DI-COVI-MARCELLO",                                                          
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LE-MIGOLE-DI-MATTEOTTI-LUCA",                                                                   
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LECHTHALER-DI-TOGN-LUIGI-E-C-S-N-C",                                                            
         "http://www.informazione-aziende.it/Azienda_ LETRARI-AZ-AGRICOLA")

thing<-gsub(" ", "", thing)

d <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=4)
colnames(d)<-c("RAGIONE SOCIALE",'ATTIVITA', 'INDIRIZZO', 'CAP')

for(i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  a<-thing[i]  
  urls<-html(a)  
  d[i,2] <- try({ urls %>% html_node(".span") %>% html_text() }, silent=TRUE)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```

Comment: WOW it's really cool!!, is `Sys.sleep(2)` gives a rest for 2 sec??

Comment: Yes, Not sure if 2 seconds is enough or too  much. Also, it's probably wise to incorporate some of the other solutions to clean the code up...