# R string and subset

Tags: r, string, character, substr, substring

I have a long html string with

Length - 1
Class and Mode -  character

```
......uygdasd class="vip" title="Click this link to access The Big Bang Theory: The Complete Fourth Season (DVD, 2011, 3-Disc Set).....
```

is it possible to extract a part of that string based on text in it. Subtract everything from `class="vip" title="Click this link to access` to `(DVD, 2011`, as a result to get this

```
The Big Bang Theory: The Complete Fourth Season
```

Thank for a help.

Comment: I think the questioner has difficulty with English and actually means "extract" (== "retain") rather than "subtract" (=="remove").

Comment: Is the pattern always "Click to access... things you want... (Extra stuff)" ?

Comment: @BondedDust i wanted to remove everything before `class="vip" title="Click this link to access` and after `class="vip" title="Click this link to access` and live only `The Big Bang Theory: The Complete Fourth Season`   Sorry For My Bad English

Comment: @rawr yes "Click to access... things you want... (Extra stuff)" is a pattern

Comment: Don't grep html... use `rvest` to parse it.

Comment: @cory if i use `rvest` has generated me a problem, till now i haven't find a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929363/r-rvest-for-and-error-server-error-503-service-unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping operators `()`. This throws away anything up to the "link to access " and after the "DVD," and only keeps the match for the second group. The expression `.+` means `<anything, of any length>`. See the `?regex` help page for further details about the interpretation of "^" and "$" and the use of `\\N` in replacements:

```
 htxt <- 'uygdasd class="vip" title="Click this link to access The Big Bang Theory: The Complete Fourth Season (DVD, 2011, 3-Disc Set).....'

gsub(pattern= "^(.+link to access )(.+)( \\(DVD,.+$)", "\\2", htxt)
[1] "The Big Bang Theory: The Complete Fourth Season"
```

There is, of course, the famous, highly-voted response to this question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)